# how to turn a list item (string type) into a module function in python 3.10

Tags: python-3.x, module, type-conversion

I had a weird idea to grab a list item and call it as module function, here is what I'm trying to do:

if you used `dir()` on **random module** it would return a list of its attributes, and I want to grab a specific item which is, in this case, **randint**, then invoke it as a working function using a,b as arguments and become in this form `randint(a, b)`
that's what I tried:

```
from random import randint  #to avoid the dot notation and make it simple
a = 10
b = 100
var = dir(random)
print(var)
# here is the result
```

[image]

```
 #randint index is 55
 print(var[55])
 >>> randint
```

I couldn't find out the type of the function randint() so I can convert the list item to it and try the following:

```
something(var[55] + "(a, b)")
```

is there a way I can achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `exec` command that can execute any string.

updated your code, the below answer should work

```
from random import randint  #to avoid the dot notation and make it simple

a = 10
b = 100
var = dir(random)
print(var)

function_string = "random_number = " + var[55] + f"({a},{b})"
#note that index number can be changed based on python version
print(function_string)
exec(function_string)
print(random_number)
```

Comment: thank you it worked, ps: the index number of randint in the list Is 55

Comment: Indexes might change with different python versions.

Comment: oh really? well that's an interesting info

Comment: Yes, for me the index was 52 as I was running python 3.9, I would suggest instead of hard coding the index, find the index of the function name as it will be consistent.